# application behavior on shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I wrote a shiny application that includes the option to add comments. To make them available all the time in the application (also after the end of the session) I use CSV files, where I write the added comments, and then read them from it for display. I put the entire application along with the mentioned CSV file on shinyapps.io and shared it with users.
Unfortunately, I noticed that daily data is reset. During the day (ECT zone) comments are saved and displayed correctly. When I start it on the second day, I turns out that the comments from the previous day are gone and are only from the current one.
I suspect that the shinyapps.io server has been set up to reset the application to the original settings, but unfortunately I have not found information on this topic.
Do you know anything more, is there such a mechanism? Do you know how I could go around him?

Answer (score 2):

When you app reaches the maximum idle limit, it will go into sleep mode, after that if you open it back up it may get a new Server and so all the Data will be gone.

The solution would be to use Resistant Storage. Easiest would be to just save the Data in Google Sheets or in Dropbox, you can read more and how to do that in the 2 Links below.

( https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Storage.html | [https://shiny.rstudio.com/../persistent-data-storage](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html#persistent) )